# Pdf to apk conversion for android application

Tags: android, eclipse, pdf, apk

I have created an application. I went to android tools in eclipse-->> Export unsigned application package-->> selected a folder for storage . However by default it is stored as pdf. And when I try to open it , it shows that the file has error or must be broken..  I want the apk to be tested on my device Google nexus 5 . Please tell me how to procede further?? What are the errors?? And should I use Export Signed or Unsigned application package??
I have attached the manifest file ..let me know if any corrections are required?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobility.visiontest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icheck_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobility.visiontest.ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.mobility.visiontest.ui.VisionAcuityTest"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mobility.visiontest.ui.IshiharaColorBlindTest"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mobility.visiontest.ui.AstigmatismTest"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mobility.visiontest.ui.DuoChromeTest"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: File show as PDF in Computer or Android Device?

Comment: I want the pdf to be converted into apk .. and then run as apk on the device

Comment: What is the content in the pdf? codes?

Comment: Yes I also tried to export signed application package in a folder , but in creates .file extension

Comment: Its really not possible, you could make a app that can read and display the PDF or get your users to download a PDF viewer.

Comment: @jenuine Whenever I try to make an apk file, by default it is making a pdf ?? What to do about it?

Comment: Make sure when you make apk then its extension .apk

Comment: @Palak yes after I created a signed apk, it was .file extension, when I changed the extension to .apk, it became a pdf.. what could be the error..

Comment: Could you provide that APK which is .file extension ?

Comment: @Palak Any other method?

Comment: Provide steps for how to sing APK

Comment: @Palak http://www.technobitez.com/how-to/create-apk-files-for-android-phone

Comment: If you only want to test (not distribute!) your app on a real mobile, you can **either** enable the USB debug setting in the developer tools **or** take the apk from the bin directory of your project and copy it to your device sdcard - then you'll need a file explorer to launch it and it will install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi if u have the apk with file with u, why do u need to open the file in pdf, just copy the file and run in ur google nexus phone. u can see the content what is present inside the apk file if doesnot contain any errors.

u can find the apk file in bin folder of ur project.

if it contains error u have to unsign the application with jarsigner like this

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore my.keystore FirstTest.apk alias_name
```

if u unsign the apk file

```
Rename the HelloTest.apk to HelloTest.zip and unzip the contents to HelloTest.
Deleted files CERT.RSA, CERT.SF under META-INF
Delete everything from the file MANIFEST.MF except the following
lines:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.0 (Android)
```

hope this hepls u